# How to implement currency conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, currency

I have tried to implement the below code but it is returning a null value.

```
[WebMethod]
public decimal ConvertGOOG(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    string url = string.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={2}{0}%3D%3F{1}", fromCurrency.ToUpper(), toCurrency.ToUpper(), amount);
    string response = web.DownloadString(url);
    Regex regex = new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d*.\\d*)");
    var val = regex.Match(response).Groups[1].Value;
    decimal rate = System.Convert.ToDecimal(regex.Match(response).Groups[1].Value);
    return rate;
}
```

From the code below I am getting val value as null. Here I am trying to convert 1 USD to INR.

I have also tried this code but getting 403 forbidden error.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(apiURL);

//Get the Response
var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

//Grab your converted value (ie 2.45 USD)
var result = Regex.Matches(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

I had tried Google API for the conversion of code but it is still returning the null value.

**How Can I Convert 1 USD to INR?**

```
[WebMethod]
        public decimal ConvertGOOG(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            string apiURL = String.Format("http://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a={0}&from={1}&to={2}", amount, fromCurrency.ToUpper(), toCurrency.ToUpper());
            string response = web.DownloadString(apiURL);
            var split = response.Split((new string[] { "<span class=bld>" }), StringSplitOptions.None);
            var value = split[1].Split(' ')[0];
            decimal rate = decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return rate;
        }
```

here is the final method for currency conversion. var value have the converted value.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  as stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d*.\\d*)"); var val = regex.Match(response).Groups[1].Value; var val contains null value

Comment: "https://www.google.com/finance/ is changed to http://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=GBP&to=$to

Implement this, it will surely resolve your issue

Comment: its working, thanks @MiteshJain

Comment: Voted to reopen, but your still missing one important piece of information that should be in your question, which is what is value of `response`

Comment: @MiteshJain, Can you add an answer so it can be accepted and closed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change you code with below code

```
    [WebMethod]
    public decimal ConvertGOOG(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
    {
        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        string apiURL = String.Format("http://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a={0}&from={1}&to={2}", amount, fromCurrency.ToUpper(), toCurrency.ToUpper());
        string response = web.DownloadString(apiURL);
        var split = response.Split((new string[] { "<span class=bld>" }), StringSplitOptions.None);
        var value = split[1].Split(' ')[0];
        decimal rate = decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return rate;
    }
```

This will return the conversion currency

Google has stopped making use of http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={2}{0}%3D%3F{1}